# Can't build crc32c(a nodejs package)

Tags: linux, centos, cryptography

It's not really nodejs related.

It's a C implementation.

Firstly, while building, it exits with error: "warning: linux/if_alg.h: No such file or directory". Then I run `yum install kernel-devel-{version}`, but it doesn't work.

Secondly when I copy the file from another PC, the error becomes "error: ‘AF_ALG’ undeclared (first use in this function)".

I have no idea to solve this issue. Please help me.

And here is my PC's info:
CPU:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5335  @ 2.00GHz

OS: CentOS 6.5

Kernel-release: 2.6.32-431.5.1.el6.x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to install the wrong package.

First, attempt to locate the correct package containing the file you need.

```
yum whatprovides */linux/if_alg.h
```

Then you will get the mysterious `No Matches found` error. This means, of course, that the file isn't provided by any package.

The reason for *that* is that the file is not in the kernel version shipped by CentOS 6; the kernel feature your program depends on only exists in newer kernels. You will need a newer kernel in order to use this software. The obvious options are to use CentOS 7, or if you won't upgrade for some reason, a third party kernel such as elrepo.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any difference between `yum provides` and `yum whatprovides`?

Comment: No, they are the same command.

Comment: What is a third party kernel? Do you mean after installing it, I will be able to build crc32c?

Comment: It's a kernel provided by a third party, of course. One commonly used example was given. Of course, you really should update to CentOS 7 if possible.

Comment: So it will replace the older kernel rather than extends it, right?